# How to pivot columns and rows in a DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid

I've bound a `DataGrid` to a `Dictionary<double, double> MyDictionary` in view model. The items in the `DataGrid` are shown like this:

[image]

But I want it to be displayed like below:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Key     |      1      |      2      |      3      |      4      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Value    |      10     |      15     |      20     |      25     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDictionary}"  
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>



private Dictionary<double, double> myDictionary = new Dictionary<double, double>
{
    {1, 10},
    {2, 15},
    {3, 20},
    {4, 25}
};
public Dictionary<double, double> MyDictionary 
{
    get { return myDictionary ; }
    set
    {
        myDictionary = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyDictionary ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "pivot".

Comment: @J.Steen Thanks. I edited the title.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2473266/5147720

Comment: @Kirenenko Oh thanks. It is not that easy as it seems then!